# Are free electrons in an ideal conductor unbound to the atoms?

Tags: electrons, classical-electrodynamics, atoms

If an ideal conductor moves without its position or geometry changes, will the electron sea remain at its previous position (because it is not compressed or anything that causes a regulation effect)? or move along with the its media (because it is trapped in its atom)?

What I mean is best understood through this example.

Assume this arrangement:

[image: motor]

A conductor disk is rotating. We attach an slider to it. and also another one to the motor shaft. And make a circuit.

If we trace an electron, will the electron path be like this?

[image: straight]

Or like this or something else?

[image: affected]

Answer (score 0):

A distinct path is impossible to justify. In reality, there exist surface current in the disc, from the shaft to the contact of the slider, and it won't be spatially uniform (not radially uniform). That is, consider any curve on the disc connnecting the axis to the slider. The current in this path will be non- zero, but this current will not be the same for all such curves.

Also, as one might intuitively guess, the surface current density is more for shorter curves from the axis to the slider(i.e : paths with lesser resistance will have more current flowing through the neighbourhood of the path).

Comment: So tell me. Will the same current pattern emerge in the disc surface if the disc is not rotating? My goal was to see if there will be any difference between the rotating and stationary situations.